# Creating an Atlas where polygons have the same attribute

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I am struggling to create the following Atlas :

I have a coverage layer containing polygons. I want to create an atlas where each map contains polygons that have the same attribute vale (blockname). The image should also be saved as the blockname.

I just cannot figure it out. By the way I am using QGIS 2.6.1. Also I am joining a csv file with attributes to the polygon layer.

Comment: Have you checked http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155278/how-to-create-an-atlas-based-on-point-attributes?rq=1

Comment: Thank you underdark. As a basic user of QGIS I just cannot figure out your link's instructions. Should I be using the filter? If so then what should the expression be? I have tried the following, to no avail :  $atlasfeature  =  "blockname". Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you want the extents to be controlled by the atlas? Or do you want the extents to stay the same and just change the symbology based on the attribute?

Comment: Jesse, hello and thank you for replying. Not sure if I understand your question. Please be patient with a newbie. I have a layer with many polygons in it. I want to create maps (with the atlas) where all the polygons has the same attribute value for a certain field. The layer is also joined with a layer (which contains a csv file). Hope I make sense. Regards

Comment: Check http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170439/large-number-of-distribution-maps-batch-maps-atlas. It's simpler and maybe enough for your needs. Try to figure out the answer to Jesse's question. It's important  for us in order to find the correct answer.